# Avoid double getElementId's within else if

Tags: javascript

I have a long list of `else if` statements.

Each one does a `document.getElementById` to check for existence of some element.

In one of of the `else if` statements to the bottom i need to not only do `getElementById` but I need to check also if that element has a certain attribute. This made me do `getElementById` twice, which i was hoping to avoid.

This is my code:

```
if (doc.getElementById('blah')) {

} else if (doc.getElementById('blah2')) {

} else if (doc.getElementById('js_blob') && doc.getElementById('js_blob').hasAttribute('action')) {
   //here
} else if (doc.getElementById('blah3')) {

} else if (doc.getElementById('blah4')) {

} else {
   console.warn('none of them');
}
```

Notice the line: `} else if (doc.getElementById('js_blob') && doc.getElementById('js_blob').hasAttribute('action')) {`

I had tried something like this and it didnt work: `} else if (var myBlobL = doc.getElementById('js_blob') && myBlobL.hasAttribute('action')) {` this would give syntax error

anyway to avoid doing double `getElementById` in this `else if` statement?

Thanks

Comment: It's a really bad example, as I'm guessing `blah` is really all different elements, and you could at least use `blah1`, `blah2` etc. to make it somewhat more correct.

Comment: And, you can't have a variable statement inside the else clause, you'd have to get the element and store it in a variable before you start the if/else madness.

Comment: Fixed up the example. Is doing it before the only way? No teriary inline trick? :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a temporary variable:

```
var tmp;

// ...
} else if ((tmp = doc.getElementById('js_blob')) && tmp.hasAttribute('action')) {
```

Comment: So cool! Thank youu!!! Note to others, if you do without the parenthesis around tmp = like this:  `} else if (tmp = doc.getElementById('js_blob') && tmp.hasAttribute('action')) {` it will fail saying `tmp is null` if it wasnt found. as it takes the second part as `tmp` as well (2nd part being `&& tmp.hasAttribute('action')`

Answer (score 1):

You can save the result in a variable, in this case you only once will call getElementById

```
var js_blob = doc.getElementById('js_blob')

if (js_blob && js_blob.hasAttribute('action')) {
}
```

I see that you have logic with many "else if", I think you can replace it on something like this

```
function fn() {
  var ids = ['elem1', 'elem2', 'elem3'],
      len = ids.length,
      i, el;

  for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    el = document.getElementById(ids[i]);

    if (el) {
      break;  
    }
  }

  if (!el) {
    return;
  }

  // work with el which has action 
  // or add logic for specific ID 

  if (el.hasAttribute('action')) {
    el.innerHTML = 'action';
  } else if (el.getAttribute('id') === 'elem2') {
    el.innerHTML = 'ELEM2';
  }
}

fn();
```

Need decrease count appeals to the DOM, in this case you just once will appeal to each element, and further will work only with copy.

Comment: True but i have a much longer list of `else if` in my true case and I was hoping to avoid any unnecessary `getElementById`, cuz actually i do `querySelector` which is slow. I have so many it really adds up.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion on how to rework, i really like @Jack's solution though its exactly what I'm looking for :)